# Seismic shot points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, land-survey

I am trying to figure out how to put in seismic shot points using ArcMap 9.3  I don't have 10.0 yet, but a project is coming up where I have to add shot points.  My PM is asking if I can add to the current shot points (or pre-plots).  The client has not yet supplied the preplots since the project is suspended til fall (she wants it done though).  I don't have any extensions such as Survey Editor, just the core ArcMap 9.3

Is there a way to do that with the current shp files of the current preplots and add to it?

Comment: I do already have the preplot shp's for the reciever and source points.

Comment: some format description would help. looking at USGS they have this as raw format...   http://walrus.wr.usgs.gov/infobank/programs/html/showfmt2html/format_400.html

Comment: I believe I just need the extensions which I don't have.  I am not sure if you just need to know the distance and direction of the shot points, or would you need to have more information then that when trying to extend the shot points?

Comment: this is confusing @zoran - pls edit the question if there is incorrect information. leaving the incorrect info and adding a comment doesn't help us understand. You do have preplots?

Comment: Sorry Brad.  I'll remember that the next time I post a question.

Yes, I have preplots..BUT, we have extended our boundaries and my PM was asking if I can create/edit the preplots to extend out into the new boundaries.  She doesn't think we will get the new preplots for a few weeks and was inquiring if I could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this data usually in an X Y M ASCII format.  I create a feature class with M values enabled and then load the data to that feature class.  I then use hatching to display the shotpoints.  Not sure if that would help but maybe point in a direction?

Comment: Hi Rob, 

I've had the preplots given to me in this format and did it once a few months back, my first time doing it in this format.  

Thanks You.

Answer (score 3):

I've developed the PetroGIS add-in, which has some tools for importing different seismic formats (such as UKOOA P1-90, SEG-P1, SPS) directly into ArcGIS point feature classes. However, it is for ArcGIS 10 only. Note also, it is not free, but you can get a fully-functional free trial from http://gis-media.com/petrogis/.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Please note our policy about full disclosure: we request that people who reference their own work, sites, or products (as you appear to do here) explicitly indicate their association with them so that we can distinguish these references from irrelevant self promotion.  Note that we do *not* discourage replies from commercial vendors about their wares, but we want readers to have enough information to assess the value of those replies.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used this, but [Exprodat has an ArcGIS 10 Add-in](http://www.exprodat.com/Blogs/blog_Labelling-2D-seismic-shot-points-in-ArcGIS-10.htm) that might be useful for this.
[image]

Comment: A clients GIS Analyst just told me about that program yesterday and am going to look into purchasing it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create the points in excel, assuming they are just an extension of the exisiting preplots.